# Uninitialized variable being used

Tags: c++

I have this code here that works pretty decent except for when we get down to the 'processData' function where I receive the error

"The variable 'totalPay' is being used without being initialized."

I've been working on this for a couple hours and my brain is going numb, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Prototypes
int readInt(string errorMsg = "", int min = INT_MIN, int max = INT_MAX);
void getData(string&, int&, char&, double&);
char getChoice(string prompt, char char1, char char2);
double processData(char service);
void display(string, int, char, double);


// Regular service
const double RCHARGE = 10.00;        // Regular service base rate for first REG_MINS.
const double RPERMIN = 0.20;         // Regular service cost per minute over REG_MINUTES.
const int REG_MINS = 50;             // Regular service free minutes.
// Premium service
const double PCHARGE = 25.00;        // Minimum charge for premium service.
const double P_PER_MIN_DAY = 0.10;   // Charge per day minutes after 75.
const double P_PER_MIN_NIGHT = 0.05; // Charge per night minutes after 100.
const int P_DAY = 75;                // Number of free minutes allowed during the day.
const int P_NIGHT = 100;             // Number of free minutes allowed during the night.

int main()
{
    string name;        // Stores the users name.
    int accountNumber;  // Stores the users account number.
    char serviceType;   // Stores the users service type.
    double minutes;     // Stores the users minutes.
    double totalPay;    // Recieves the total pay from processData.
    bool loopies = true;// Controls the loop while condition is true.


    while (loopies == true)
    {
        getData(name, accountNumber, serviceType, minutes);

        totalPay = processData(serviceType);

        display(name, accountNumber, serviceType, totalPay);
    }



    return 0;
}
// Checks ints to make sure they are valid.
int readInt(string errorMsg, int min, int max)
{
    int someInt;
    bool valid = false;

    do
    {
        // User entering account number
        cin >> someInt;

        // Verifying the data is valid (0 to 9999)
        valid = (someInt >= min && someInt <= max);

        // Clearing out invalid data and prompting for re-entry
        if (cin.fail() || !valid || !isspace(cin.peek()))
        {
            cout << "Error! Invalid input." << endl;
            cout << errorMsg << " must be whole number between " << min << " and " << max << endl;
            cout << "Try Again: ";
            cin.clear(); // Clearing the fail state
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            valid = false;
        }
    } while (!valid);

    // Clears out following incorrect data once correct
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    return someInt;
}
// Takes all user data and checks input.
void getData(string &name, int &account, char &service, double &bill)
{

    cout << "Enter customer name or \"Exit\" to end program: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    if (name == "Exit" || name == "EXIT" || name == "exit")
    {
        cout << "Program closing..." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    cout << "Enter account number: ";
    account = readInt("Account", 0, 10000);

    cout << "Enter service type (R for regular or P for premium): ";
    service = getChoice("Service", 'r', 'p' );

}

char getChoice(string input, char char1, char char2)
{
    char character;     // Stores the users character.
    bool valid = false; // Controls the loop.

    do
    {


        cin >> character;
        character = tolower(character);


        valid = (character == char1 || character == char2);


        if (!valid || !isspace(cin.peek())) {
            cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
            cout << input << " needs to be " << char1 << " or " << char2 << endl;
            cout << "Try again: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            valid = false;
        }
    } while (!valid);

    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    return toupper(character);
}

double processData(char service)
{
    int dayMin;      // Stores the users day minutes.
    int nightMin;    // Stores the users night minutes.
    double totalPay; // Stores the total pay.
    double dayPay;   // Stores the pay for day minutes.
    double nightPay; // Stores the pay for night minutes.

    if (service == 'r')
    {
        cout << "Enter minutes used: ";
        cin >> dayMin;
        dayMin = readInt("Minutes ", 0, INT_MAX);

        if (dayMin > REG_MINS)
        {
            dayMin -= REG_MINS;
            totalPay = (dayMin * RPERMIN) + RCHARGE;
        }
        else
        {
            totalPay = RCHARGE;
        }
        totalPay = nightPay + dayPay - RCHARGE;
    }
    else if (service == 'p')
    {
        cout << "Enter day minutes: ";
        cin >> dayMin;
        dayMin = readInt("Minutes ", 0, INT_MAX);

        if (dayMin > P_DAY)
        {
            dayMin -= P_DAY;
            dayPay = (dayMin * P_PER_MIN_DAY) + PCHARGE;
        }
        else
        {
            dayPay = PCHARGE;
        }

        cout << "Enter night minutes: ";
        cin >> nightMin;
        nightMin = readInt("Minutes ", 0, INT_MAX);

        if (nightMin > P_NIGHT)
        {
            nightMin -= P_NIGHT;
            nightPay = (nightMin * P_PER_MIN_NIGHT) + PCHARGE;
        }
        else
        {
            nightPay = PCHARGE;
        }

    }
    return totalPay;
}

void display(string name, int account, char service, double bill)
{
    string switchService;

    switch (service)
    {
    case 'R':
        switchService = "Regular";
        break;
    case 'P':
        switchService = "Premium";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Invalid character.";
    }

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Customer Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Account number: " << account << endl;
    cout << "Service type: " << switchService << endl;
    cout << "Amount due: $" << bill << endl << endl;

}
```

Comment: Try to initialize `totalPay` outside main method.

Comment: @RajeshN Thanks for the suggestion but this did not work.

Comment: `getChoice` always returns an uppercase character  - it has a `toupper` call in the `return` statement. `processData` then compares this character to lowercase `'r'` and `'p'`; naturally, these comparisons can never possibly hold, and `totalPay` is then never assigned a value.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik YESS! this fixed my original problem but revealed more behind it. thank you!

Comment: That's way too much code for a very isolated problem. In order to find the actual cause of the problem, reduce the code to the bare minimum that is required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `processData()`, if `service` is neither `p` nor `r`, `totalPay` is never assigned before returning.

You may initialize it on declaration like

```
double totalPay = 0.0;
```

Comment: *"if `service` is neither `p` nor `r`"* - it's not assigned for `p` - only `r`.